# How do I specify the file directory for it to run in task scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I added this batch file into the task scheduler but it couldn't be load and it keeps looping and most probably it is because of the file directory that I have wrote. But if I was to run this batch file from the local directory instead, this batch file can be run. So, how do I change the file directory in the if statement to allow it to run it in the task scheduler? What path do I need to use?

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

:CheckForFile

if exist "MATS\NX_EXTR.txt" %AND% if exist "MTA\NX_EXTR.txt" goto FileExists
timeout 1
goto :CheckForFile

:FileExists

 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (MATS\NX_EXTR.txt) DO SET "L2a=%%a"&SET "L1a="&GOTO nextstep
 :nextstep
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (MTA\NX_EXTR.txt) DO (
 IF DEFINED L1a (ECHO(%%a) ELSE (SET "L1a=%%a"&CALL :sumlines)
)
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%a IN (MATS\NX_EXTR.txt) DO (ECHO(%%a)
) >C.txt

TYPE C.txt

GOTO :EOF

:sumlines
SET /a L2a=1%L1a:~10%+1%L2a:~10%
ECHO(%L1a:~0,10%%L2a:~1%
GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems familar somehow...

```
if exist "MATS\NX_EXTR.txt" %AND% if exist "MTA\NX_EXTR.txt" goto FileExists
```

First, `%AND%` is not required. if exist *filename* if exist *filename2* something parameters

will execute `something` (even if it's a `goto`) when both files exist.

This will probably work as it stands **because** `and` is undefined and thus `%and%` is resolved to an empty string.

In all probability, the problem is that `MATS\NX_EXTR.txt` is a **relative** pathname to a file - it's short for `.\MATS\NX_EXTR.txt` and hence finding the file depends on the **current directory**.

Your fix is to either

change to he appropriate directory within the batch by executing

```
 cd "d:\parent\of"
```

where `d:\parent of" is the parent directoru of`MATS\NX_EXTR.txt`(ie. the **absolute filepath** is`d:\parent of\MATS\NX_EXTR.txt`

OR

replace MATS\NX_EXTR.txt with the **absolute filepath** (ie. `d:\parent of\MATS\NX_EXTR.txt`)

Naturally, you'd needto repeat this for each of the filenames you use, including `C.txt`

---

In order to keep from having to maintain this batch, you could also use

```
set "file1=d:\parent of\MATS\NX_EXTR.txt"
```

at the start of the program, and then use `%file1%` to refer to the file. Obviously, repeat for all files - and possibly even change the symbolic name `file1` to something that may carry some meaning (`newdatafile`) for instance)

---

Revision example (I've no idea of your actual absolute filenames)

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

set "file1=c:\wherever\MATS\NX_EXTR.txt"
set "file2=c:\wherever\MTA\NX_EXTR.txt"
set "file3=c:\wherever\C.txt"

:CheckForFile

if exist "%file1%" if exist "%file2%" goto FileExists
timeout 1
goto :CheckForFile

:FileExists

 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (%file1%) DO SET "L2a=%%a"&SET "L1a="&GOTO nextstep
 :nextstep
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (%file2%) DO (
 IF DEFINED L1a (ECHO(%%a) ELSE (SET "L1a=%%a"&CALL :sumlines)
)
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%a IN (%file1%) DO (ECHO(%%a)
) >%file3%

TYPE %file3%

GOTO :EOF

:sumlines
SET /a L2a=1%L1a:~10%+1%L2a:~10%
ECHO(%L1a:~0,10%%L2a:~1%
GOTO :eof
```

Note that if the value assigned to `%filen%` contains separators such as <kbd>Space</kbd> then `%filen%` must be quoted (`"%%file3%"`).

If this results in the format

```
for /f ... in ("...") ...
```

then you need to add the `usebackq` option in `for /f`

eg.

```
FOR /f "USEBACKQdelims=" %%a IN ("%file2%") DO (
```

(caps used for emphasis; `usebackq` can be in any case)

If `for /f ...` is applied to "a string" *without* the `usebackq` option, then the `"quoted string"` is parsed, not the data in `"the\file whose name \is in\the\quoted string"`